# edit this code to add a condition to reverse the formula based on specific text value in rows

Tags: vba, macros, formula

```
Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]=""N/A"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met""))))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(a, 14))
```

The code is currently working but I want to add something. Let's say add a condition that

```
(IF G2 = "AR17 - Standard Report" or "IT18 - Standard Report" or "CSYT - Standard Report", then the calculation should be (RC[-2]<=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met and if not, the calculation should be RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met)
```

To make things more clear. I want to reverse the current formula for all rows that has "AR17 - Standard Report", "IT18 - Standard Report" and "CSYT - Standard Report". I have thousands of data so i want all the rows which have those values to have a reversed formula. I hope someone can help me. I am quite new to VBA.

Edited: Now this is the code that i have. No errors but still, formulas aren't changing for those specified texts in G column.

```
    Range("N2").Select
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("G2"), Array("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), False)) Then
    'First statement
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]<=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met"")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(a, 14))
Else
    'Second
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]=""N/A"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met""))))"
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(a, 14))
End If
```

Comment: you dont reverse because in the 2 conditions you have RC[-2 ]=RC[-4]

Comment: what do you mean? how can i apply your suggestion to fix the problem?

Comment: Must applies it to row you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have Excel at home, but you can try this :

```
MAXROW = 20000 ' number of rows you have 
'edit
for i = 2 to MAXROW
    Range("N" & i).Select
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("G"& i), Array("AR17 - Standard Report", "IT18 - Standard Report" , "CSYT - Standard Report" ), False)) Then
        'First statement
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =  "=IF(RC[-2]<=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met"")"
    else
        'Second
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-2]=""NA"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]=""N/A"",""N/A"",IF(RC[-2]>=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met""))))"
    endif
 Next
```

You can adjust the formula by seeing what macro recording gives to you.

Comment: replacing my code with yours does not give me error but still, formulas for the specified texts inside the array isn't changed.

Comment: i think the first one was way better because that code now has an error. i think the first one just need some modification. By the way, G column soud be "F" but i have tried changing it but it still doesn't work. What am i missing -_-

Comment: the code below, test rows from g2 to g20000, if Gi in (AR17 ...) then update cell Ni with first formula, else update with second formula. you can checck you're formula after executing the macro.

Comment: code must be in vba macro : sub updateMyrows() . and then executing

Comment: take a look at your 2 formulas, because they dont exclude each other if RC[-2]=RC[-4]

Comment: error 1004 and this is the one higlighted with yellow: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]<=RC[-4],""Met"",""Not Met)"

Comment: I fixed a typo, if doesnt work : record a macro, type you formula in a cell , then catch the result. repaet for the second case and reaplce in my code. It's a typo problem i think

Comment: oh man it worked! thanks a lot man! i will just comment here again if something goes wrong. thanks again!

Comment: just one thing. how can i be able to not set specific rows because my data are always changing and rows are different all the time

Comment: Need more information, how many rows, structure, how many columns etc.. maybe vba is not the solution ( you can combine a vlookup with 3 if, directly in a formula)